# How to show the values of some html fields to a table in print mode

Tags: html, css

I have a html page with some charts, labels, textboxes, etc and want to show some of the labels and textbox values in a table format on the print mode.

I am using @media print in my css style where I can relocate/resize stuff when user press ctrl + p to print the page.

```css
@media print {
    button, .no-print {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .myclass-print {
        border: none !important;
        position: absolute;
        top: 670px;
        left: 420px;
    }

    .comment-print {
        position: absolute;
        top: 1010px;
        left: 40px;
        width: 360px;
        word-break: break-all;
    }

    .no-border-print {
        border: none;
    }

    aside#sidebar, header[role="banner"], footer, #comments, #respond {
        display: none;
    }

    .page-header {
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: none;
    }
}
<div class="myclass-print">
     @Html.Partial("~/_MyPartial.cshtml")
</div>
```

in _MyPartial.cshtml I have some textbox components in an html table. I want to just print the value of them in the print mode, i.e., no dropdown box or textbox appears on the print but just their content (text). I would be happy if someone can share the solution with me.

Comment: pls share html code also

Comment: @Ranjithv the html is not really important it has got some images, drop-down boxes, text boxes, etc, and I think camaulay answered that correctly. I made redundant tables with spans in them and when the user wants to print it will use them. BTW, as I am using knock out therefore I did not need to use the addEventListener beforeprint, and simply bound knockout observable objects to my new table items.. and just hide them on the normal view and make them visible on print view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to assign the values of the textboxes to other elements elsewhere on the page using JavaScript.

Only show these elements when you print.
Hide the input text boxes on print.

Working Example:

```js
// When the user prints
window.addEventListener("beforeprint", function(event) {

  // Assign the value from the input to the print only span innerText
  document.getElementById('sample-input-text').innerText = document.getElementById('sample-input').value;
});
```

```css
.print-only {
  display: none;
}

.no-print {
  display: block;
}

@media print {
  .print-only {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .no-print {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="no-print" type="text" value="Sample Text" name="sample-input" id="sample-input">
<span class="print-only" id="sample-input-text"></span>
```